# Form will not send

Tags: javascript, forms

I am not a coder, but copied this form from one page I own to another and can't get it to send. It is a js script and I've checked its syntax online and the validators say it's ok, but the form will not send. It works fine on the other page. I notice it does not have a  tag, but on the other page it does not prevent it from sending. What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
Not Set/title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="orcallus">Call Us:</div>
<div id="ourphone"><a href="tel:214-644-6683">214-644-6683</a></div>
<div id="form2"><br>
    <div id="orcallus">Or WE'LL CALL YOU...</div>
    <div id="contactform">use our handy  Form below...</div>
    <div id="error" style="display:none;font-weight:bold;color:red;">Please enter valid information for all fields.</div>
    <div class="mobile_name">Name</div>
    <input id="mobile_name2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_phone">Phone</div>
    <input id="mobile_phone2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_fromzip">Move from ZIP</div>
    <input id="mobile_fromzip2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_tozip">Move to ZIP</div>
    <input id="mobile_tozip2" type="text" />
    <div id="submit_form" style="margin-top: 12px"><a style="color: black; text-decoration: underline; margin-top: 12px"; onClick="goog_report_conversion">CALL ME</a></div>
    <br>
    <div id="thanks2">Thank you! We will contact you shortly.</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $('#thanks').show();
            $('#form').hide();
            var phone = $('#userphone').val();
            $.post("../mobileform.php", { phone:phone });
        });
        $('#submit_form').die('click');
        $('#submit_form').click(function() {
            var name = $('#mobile_name2').val();
            var phone = $('#mobile_phone2').val();
            var fromzip = $('#mobile_fromzip2').val();
            var tozip = $('#mobile_tozip2').val();
            if (name.length < 3 || phone.length < 10 || fromzip.length <5 || tozip.length < 5) { 
                $('#error').show();
            } else {
                $.post("../mobileform.php", { name:name, phone:phone, fromzip:fromzip, tozip:tozip });
                $('#thanks2').show();
                $('#form2').hide();
                $('#error').hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script> 
<script>
var myvar=setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery('#thanks2').text()=="Thank you! We will contact you shortly."){
ga('send','event','form','submit','call me');
clearInterval(myvar);
}
},1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is `#submit`?

Comment: you're missing [jquery] (https://jquery.com/), this lib should so before the 'jquery' code .

Comment: Where's the `<form>`?

Comment: @j08691 He doesn't need a form. As you can see in his ajax post he's grabbing the values manually instead of serializing a form.

Comment: If you can open your browser's "developer tools", check if there are any red-highlighted errors. Most browsers, you can open the developer tools by clicking F12. Or, right click on the web page and go to "inspect element"

Comment: I was able to use your solution to get it to send. It may have been the extra semi-colon. However, the 'Thank you' message doesn't come up after sending.

Answer (score 0):

**Relevant Fixes:**

1. As [@akram-saouri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5562623/akram-saouri) mentioned, you'll need to import the jQuery library. You can do this by adding the following code between the `<head>` and `<meta>` tags.

   ```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   ```
2. Form submission triggers the PHP file `../mobileform.php`. Nothing will happen on the backend if this file does not exist. Even without this file, the client will still function and appear to submit correctly.
3. jQuery's `.die()` function has been deprecated. You don't need it anyways. Just comment out that line, or delete it.
4. In an `<a>` tag on line 26, there is an extra semicolon before the `onClick`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Not Set</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="orcallus">Call Us:</div>
   <div id="ourphone"><a href="tel:214-644-6683">214-644-6683</a></div>
   <div id="form2"><br>
    <div id="orcallus">Or WE'LL CALL YOU...</div>
    <div id="contactform">use our handy Form below...</div>
    <div id="error" style="display:none;font-weight:bold;color:red;">Please enter valid information for all fields.</div>
    <div class="mobile_name">Name</div> <input id="mobile_name2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_phone">Phone</div> <input id="mobile_phone2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_fromzip">Move from ZIP</div> <input id="mobile_fromzip2" type="text" />
    <div class="mobile_tozip">Move to ZIP</div> <input id="mobile_tozip2" type="text" />
    <div id="submit_form" style="margin-top: 12px"><a style="color: black; text-decoration: underline; margin-top: 12px">CALL ME</a></div> <br> 
   </div>
            <div id="thanks2">Thank you! We will contact you shortly.</div>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#thanks2").hide();
     $('#submit').click(function () {
      $('#thanks').show();
      $('#form').hide();
      var phone = $('#userphone').val();
      $.post("../mobileform.php", {
       phone: phone
      });
     });
     //$('#submit_form').die('click');
     $('#submit_form').click(function () {
      var name = $('#mobile_name2').val();
      var phone = $('#mobile_phone2').val();
      var fromzip = $('#mobile_fromzip2').val();
      var tozip = $('#mobile_tozip2').val();
      if (name.length < 3 || phone.length < 10 || fromzip.length < 5 || tozip.length < 5) {
       $('#error').show();
      } else {
       $.post("../mobileform.php", {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        fromzip: fromzip,
        tozip: tozip
       });
       $('#thanks2').show();
       $('#form2').hide();
       $('#error').hide();
      }
     });
    });
   </script>
   <script>
    /* Commented out for sanity during testing */
    /*var myvar = setInterval(function () {
     if (jQuery('#thanks2').text() == "Thank you! We will contact you shortly.") {
      ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'call me');
      clearInterval(myvar);
     }
    }, 1000);*/
   </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

---

**Additional Suggestions:**

1. Some of your tags are left unclosed.

   - Replace the `/title>` with the full closing tag `</title>` (and maybe consider changing it from "Not Set"?)
   - After the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>` tag, you should throw in a `</head>`.
2. The last `<script>` tag is unnecessary, since some other components are missing, and it won't affect how the page itself functions. If you decide to keep it in:

   - The last script segment should be placed in the `$(document).ready(function(){` of the previous `<script>` tag. This reduces the chance that you'll return any from incomplete document loading.
   - You'll need to set up [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/), and modify your code accordingly.
3. In an `<a>` tag on line 26, the function called by `onClick="goog_report_conversion"` is not defined. This part should be removed, or Google Analytics should be set up.

Comment: Thanks much. I removed some things and got a little sloppy. The last script contains Google tracking code. Exactly where would I insert it in the $(document).ready(function(){ of the previous <script> tag?

Comment: Inserting that code directly after the `$(document).ready(function(){` would work just fine. If this helped you, remember to upvote a good solution, and mark what worked for you as "accepted", as in the [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Welcome to the SO community!

Comment: I added the jquery link, closed the <title> tag, and added the </head> tag. The mobileform.php does exist.

Comment: Glad you're making progress! Hope it all works out for you!

Comment: It still won't submit.

Comment: I am new on this site, but I find it confusing. Someone gave me a good solution above, but I think I commented on the wrong one. Whoever it was said 'In an <a> tag on line 26, there is an extra semicolon before the onClick.' and that seemed to get it to send, in addition to adding the full jquery link. It still does not display the 'Thank you' message after sending.

Comment: @JAndrews I've updated the code in my post, but since it's not a bug I haven't changed the "fixes" or "suggestions" sections. I simply moved the `<div id="thanks2">` element out from the `#form2` element, and added in a `$("#thanks2").hide();` after the `$(document).ready(function(){`. Remember to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it can be marked closed, and others can benefit from this great question!